# Columns to Rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I am trying to do the following operation in `pandas`. Any suggestions on `pandas` way of doing this?

```
In [1]: input  = pd.DataFrame({"X_1": [1], "X_2": [2], "X_3": [5], "Y_1": [1.2], "Y_2": [2.3], "Y_3": [3.4]})

In [2]: input
Out[2]: 
   X_1  X_2  X_3  Y_1  Y_2  Y_3
0    1    2    5  1.2  2.3  3.4

In [3]: output = pd.DataFrame({"X": [1,2,5], "Y": [1.2, 2.3, 3.4]})

In [4]: output
Out[4]: 
   X    Y
0  1  1.2
1  2  2.3
2  5  3.4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str.split` and `stack`.

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df.stack().loc[0]

   X    Y
1  1  1.2
2  2  2.3
3  5  3.4
```

#### Note: Index is `[1, 2, 3]` matching original columns.

Comment: wau, nice improving of my answer.. But I think if there is multiple rows in original `df`, you have to use `reset_index` - see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37841281/2901002)

Comment: Thanks guys.  @jezrael `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4, 6), columns=['X_1', 'X_2', 'X_3', 'Y_1', 'Y_2', 'Y_3'])` then do `df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)` and then `df.stack()`  leave off the `.loc[0]`

Comment: Ok, no problem. Nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best answer, but you can do the following:

```
a = {"X_1": [1], "X_2": [2], "X_3": [5], "Y_1": [1.2], "Y_2": [2.3], "Y_3": [3.4]}
x = [a[key][0] for key in sorted(a.keys()) if 'X' in key]  
y = [a[key][0] for key in sorted(a.keys()) if 'Y' in key]
df = pd.DataFrame([x, y]).T
```

yielding:

> ```
>      0    1
> 0  1.0  1.2
> 1  2.0  2.3
> 2  5.0  3.4
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can first [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) columns by `_` and create [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.unique.html) values `a` and `b`. Then create [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
cols = input.columns.str.split('_')
print (cols)
Index([['X', '1'], ['X', '2'], ['X', '3'], ['Y', '1'], 
       ['Y', '2'], ['Y', '3']], dtype='object')

a = cols.str[0].unique()
print (a)
['X' 'Y']

b = cols.str[1].unique()
print (b)
['1' '2' '3']

input.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a,b])
print (input.stack(1).reset_index(drop=True))
   X    Y
0  1  1.2
1  2  2.3
2  5  3.4
```

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of thing, I prefer a `melt` followed by a string operation, followed by a `pivot`:

```
df = pd.melt(input)
df[['column', 'index']] = df['variable'].str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.pivot(index='index', columns='column', values='value')
print(df)
```

output:

```
column    X    Y
index           
1       1.0  1.2
2       2.0  2.3
3       5.0  3.4
```